# Where to put/generate large javascript data files in front end with cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I have an app that uses a large database to fill in google maps and charts data. This ends up being about 5000 lines per column and about 20 columns. The issue I am running into is whether to put this data in the view template, which makes my source code several thousand lines long, or generating a javascript file for each instance and including them in the view. The issue I am running into with that method is that I am generating files with no way to delete them out of the webroot folder (without a cron job to go through and delete old ones). I was wondering what the solution is for this.

Comment: why would you want to save it into a file? Save it in a Database and then render only the necessary things (asynchronous loading, not all at once...) into a view.

Comment: So the information is stored in a database, but to get them to the view I would have to translate that information into javascript correct?

Answer (score 1):

of course, but you as a developer are responsable for fast delivering websites. you cannot fetch all of the data. for example when using google maps it is common practice that you display a limited number of data according to the displayed area ( rectangle ). When using charts, then you should answer only with the already aggregated data.

there is almost never the reason to display all the data to the user. Ask yourself, what will you do when you see 5000 thousands lines of code on the website. do you need it all at once? No.

Use `AJAX` to fetch only the rows you need right now.